# "no space left on device", yet df shows plent of space and inodes

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've got two hard drives attached to this Ubuntu Server 14.04 system - one 1TB HDD, and one 2TB HDD.

They are mounted in `/mnt/1TB` and `/mnt/2TB`. I would like to copy the contents of the 1TB drive to the 2TB drive, however I get the following error: `No space left on device`.

There is however, as reported by `df`, plenty of space *and* inodes:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdc6       869G  401G  425G  49% /mnt/1TB
/dev/sdb        1.8T  765G  976G  44% /mnt/2TB


Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdc6       57851904  231339  57620565    1% /mnt/1TB
/dev/sdb       122101760 2058153 120043607    2% /mnt/2TB
```

Are there any other reasons why the device may be showing as full?

Comment: What is the sector size on both drives?

Comment: According to `fdisk`, `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes`. I'm copying an old home directory to the 2TB drive, and deleting `.cache` and `.local` (which both contained a lot of files) is allowing me to transfer again, so I'm wondering if maybe the inode count is showing up incorrectly.

Comment: Can you show the exact command you are using? And which filesystems are used on the HDDs? (`mount` output?!)

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/mtab`, `lsblk`, and `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` (all three of these).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you inadvertently mounted the 2TB device itself rather than one of the partitions on it, as evidenced by `/dev/sdb` rather than e.g. `/dev/sdb1`.

First be sure the 2TB device has valid, formatted partitions on it to receive the data (skip this step if you've already formatted the drive and just made a typo when mounting):

1. Unmount `/dev/sdb`
2. Run `sudo gparted /dev/sdb` (install `gparted` if you don't have it)
3. Set up the partitions appropriately

If you've already formatted `/dev/sdb` without actually creating a partition then you made a minor mistake there (still usable but weird) and you'd want to rebuild the MBR with `gparted` before partitioning and formatting if necessary.

After this, for good measure, do `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` to force the system to reread the partition table and create the appropriate `/dev/sdbN` devices. Perhaps this is the step you originally missed and were misled by the lack of `/dev/sdbN`?

Then mount the partition, e.g. `mount /dev/sdb1` and copy to it.

Alternatively you can just use `gparted` to copy the partition directly from the source drive to the destination drive, then increase the destination drive partition size to the full 2TB -- this is what I would do.

Comment: Why on Earth is using sdb a mistake? Just because you are used to partition hard drives when you need more than one, doesn't mean there is any need for it if you plan to use the hole device... Your 'weirdness' comes from habit.

Comment: @Bgs Using SuperFloppy for hard drives is a mistake, and I like to not break compatibility with all tools on all OSes in existence by not using a partition table and an MBR. Of course, as I said, its still usable if you'd like to do it that way, but youd have to use cp after formatting or dd then resize the fs manually as gparted won't work with no partition table. Not convenient and not an exact copy. Do what the op wants with no partition table on the destination and see for yourself. ;)

Comment: Why oh why is a mistake? Do tell me! I've never seen a tool on any unix system that couldn't handle this out of the box. (Actually they don't care as long as it's a block device.) I've never used a Windows tool on a Unix disk except when moving the disk to a Windows system. In that case it's a full wipe anyway. I don't even get what you mean by the cp/dd/gparted part. Why would I try to use a partitioning tool if there are no partitions? For disk data transfer: dd+expand fs and you are done. I've been using disks without partitions for over 20 years and never had any problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a suspected big file/folder by running this, it will tell you all files/folders sizes:

`du ~ -h|sort -r -n|less`

it will also sort so the biggest file/folder will go first at the top of your screen.

And don't forget to clean the Trash/Rubbish Bin anyway.